# Performance downgrades when connecting to DisplayLink docking station

Tags: dock, thunderbolt-display

When I connect the MacBook to the DockingStation, the performance of the system drops drastically (even opening Mission Control, the operation happens in frames).

If although I connect the external monitors (2x27") with two [Apple Multiport Adapters](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MUF82AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter), the performance is great. Therefore the problem only exists when connecting to the DockingStation via DisplayLink.

Any suggestions?

Laptop:

- HardWare: MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019), i7, 16GB DDR4, AMD Radeon Pro 5300M 4GB
- Software:

  - macOS BigSur 11.4
  - Display Link Manager 1.4.0 (Build 57.120)

Docking Station:

- [HP USB-C Universal Dock](https://support.hp.com/id-en/document/c05639574)

Comment: Why are you using DisplayLink in the first place?

Comment: The docking station requires DisplayLink to work. Otherwise I get nothing out of it.